# Android Studio Java - How do I use a random array without repeating?

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio, random, shuffle

I've got an array of random messages, but I want it so that it doesn't pick a message that has already been picked and then reset once all messages have been picked.

```
public void showRandomMsg(){
        shuffleMsg();
        answer1.setText((messageArray[0].getmAns()));
        message2.setText((messageArray[0].getmMsg()));
        toyView1.setImageResource(messageArray[0].getmImage());
    }

Messages m01 = new Messages(R.drawable.crown1, "Mesage 0 A","Message 0 B");
Messages m02 = new Messages(R.drawable.crown2,"Mesage 1 A","Message 1 B");
Messages m03 = new Messages(R.drawable.crown3,"Mesage 2 A","Message 2 B");
Messages m04 = new Messages(R.drawable.crown4,"Mesage 3 A","Message 3 B");
Messages m05 = new Messages(R.drawable.crown5,"Mesage 4 A","Message 4 B");

Messages [] messageArray=new Messages[]{
        m01, m02, m03, m04, m05
};

public void shuffleMsg(){
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(messageArray));

}
```

Comment: For non-repetition you could shuffle the message array and work through the shuffled array in order.  Only reshuffle when you have used all the messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write logic for the message getter which removes one message, and in the event that no message be available, repopulates:

```java
List<Messages> messageList;

public void showRandomMsg(){
    if (Objects.isNull(messageList) || messageList.size() == 0) {
        refillMsg();
    }
    answer1.setText(messageList.remove(0).getmAns());
    message2.setText(messageList.remove(0).getmMsg());
    toyView1.setImageResource(messageList.remove(0).getmImage());
}

public void refillMsg() {
    messageList = Arrays.asList(new Messages[] {
        m01, m02, m03, m04, m05
    });
    Collections.shuffle(messageList);
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks a lot, this is actually an elegant way of doing it!